# interactive Button doesn't hide the chart as I intended

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to link a set of data to each green button up in the display: I'd like to click the button and display half of the curves in my graph. I created the buttons, the function and linked data but it doesn't work. The end goal is to click the button (a month) and display just a portion of the three curves:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Covid Piemonte 2020</title>
    <h1>Evoluzione del virus Covid-19 nel bimestre marzo-aprile 2020 (Piemonte)</h1>
    
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="updateChart()">MARZO</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="updateChart1()">APRILE</button>
    <br>
    
    

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="720" height="360"></canvas>

    </div>

    <script>
        var label1 = ['16-marzo', '17-marzo', '18-marzo', '19-marzo', '20-marzo', '21-marzo', '22-marzo', '23-marzo', '24-marzo', '25-marzo', '26-marzo', '27-marzo', '28-marzo', '29-marzo', '30-marzo', '31-marzo', '1-aprile', '2-aprile', '3-aprile', '4-aprile', '5-aprile', '6-aprile', '7-aprile', '8-aprile', '9-aprile', '10-aprile', '11-aprile', '12-aprile', '13-aprile', '14-aprile', '15-aprile', '16-aprile', '17-aprile', '18-aprile', '19-aprile', '20-aprile', '21-aprile', '22-aprile', '23-aprile', '24-aprile', '25-aprile', '26-aprile', '27-aprile', '28-aprile', '29-aprile', '30-aprile'];


        var olddata = [5589, 6872, 8140, 9424, 10590, 11799, 12869, 14619, 16110, 17509, 18486, 20197, 22829, 24782, 26578, 28918, 31135, 33431, 36547, 38638, 40638, 43306, 46927, 51311, 55548, 60271, 65391, 69003, 71615, 74060, 78066, 83130, 89136, 94278, 99008, 102082, 107850, 113930, 120387, 127108, 132510, 137069, 140996, 146173, 152447, 158762, 164053, 170109];
        var olddata1= [1516, 2063, 2659, 3017, 3576, 4059, 4541, 5094, 5767, 6193, 6708, 7228, 7920, 8461, 8835, 9418, 9918, 10466, 11082, 11839, 12442, 13046, 13434, 13964, 14671, 15412, 16109, 16733, 17246, 17773, 18446, 19261, 19954, 20581, 21144, 21437, 22149, 22854, 23319, 24050, 24549, 24910, 25216, 25538, 25995, 26453];
        var olddata2= [111, 144, 166, 183, 224, 255, 300, 336, 403, 483, 545, 598, 662, 734, 795, 854, 924, 1018, 1088, 1144, 1191, 1284, 1349, 1349, 1417, 1487, 1591, 1689, 1788, 1876, 1969, 2064, 2146, 2224, 2302, 2379, 2453, 2524, 2598, 2668, 2737, 2803, 2859, 2913, 2966, 3032, 3086];

        let myChart = (document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'));
        let myCovidChart = new Chart(myChart, {
            type: 'line', 
            data:{
                labels:label1,
                datasets:[{
                    data:olddata,
                    label: 'numero cumulativo dei Tamponi',
                    borderColor:'green',
                   

                },{
                    data:olddata1,
                    label: 'Numero incrementale dei contagiati', 
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    

                },{
                    data: olddata2,
                    label: 'Numero incrementale dei decessi',
                    borderColor: 'blue',
                  
                }]
            },
            options:{
 
            }
        });

        function updateChart(){
   
            {

                      function updateChart(){
        chart.data.datasets[0].data = [74060, 78066, 83130, 89136, 94278, 99008, 102082, 107850, 113930, 120387, 127108, 132510, 137069, 140996, 146173, 152447, 158762, 164053, 170109];
        chart.update();
        }  
            }

        };
        

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I see two issues with your current code.

1. Your chart variable is `myCovidChart`, but in `updateChart` you reference `chart`.
2. Your function `updateChart` defines a local function also called `updateChart`, but doesn't call it.

These can be fixed by changing the `updateChart` function to:

```js
function updateChart() {
    myCovidChart.data.datasets[0].data = [120387, 127108, 132510, 137069, 140996, 146173, 152447, 158762, 164053, 170109];
    myCovidChart.update();
}
```

Comment: Tried what you said but still no results... nothing changes at all.

Comment: Are you sure this has replaced your outer updateChart function, not just the inner one? And are you sure you've saved the file and reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

As domdomegg pointed out in his answer your update function was not correct, the chart pointed to the wrong variable because `chart` was nothing because you stored the chart in the `myCovidChart`, also the update function didnt work because you nested it double with a lot of extra brackets so it couldnt find the variable anymore. If you remove all extra clutter and point to the right variable it will work

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Covid Piemonte 2020</title>
  <h1>Evoluzione del virus Covid-19 nel bimestre marzo-aprile 2020 (Piemonte)</h1>

  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="updateChart()">MARZO</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="updateChart1()">APRILE</button>
  <br>



</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="720" height="360"></canvas>

  </div>

  <script>
    var label1 = ['16-marzo', '17-marzo', '18-marzo', '19-marzo', '20-marzo', '21-marzo', '22-marzo', '23-marzo', '24-marzo', '25-marzo', '26-marzo', '27-marzo', '28-marzo', '29-marzo', '30-marzo', '31-marzo', '1-aprile', '2-aprile', '3-aprile', '4-aprile', '5-aprile', '6-aprile', '7-aprile', '8-aprile', '9-aprile', '10-aprile', '11-aprile', '12-aprile', '13-aprile', '14-aprile', '15-aprile', '16-aprile', '17-aprile', '18-aprile', '19-aprile', '20-aprile', '21-aprile', '22-aprile', '23-aprile', '24-aprile', '25-aprile', '26-aprile', '27-aprile', '28-aprile', '29-aprile', '30-aprile'];


    var olddata = [5589, 6872, 8140, 9424, 10590, 11799, 12869, 14619, 16110, 17509, 18486, 20197, 22829, 24782, 26578, 28918, 31135, 33431, 36547, 38638, 40638, 43306, 46927, 51311, 55548, 60271, 65391, 69003, 71615, 74060, 78066, 83130, 89136, 94278, 99008, 102082, 107850, 113930, 120387, 127108, 132510, 137069, 140996, 146173, 152447, 158762, 164053, 170109];
    var olddata1 = [1516, 2063, 2659, 3017, 3576, 4059, 4541, 5094, 5767, 6193, 6708, 7228, 7920, 8461, 8835, 9418, 9918, 10466, 11082, 11839, 12442, 13046, 13434, 13964, 14671, 15412, 16109, 16733, 17246, 17773, 18446, 19261, 19954, 20581, 21144, 21437, 22149, 22854, 23319, 24050, 24549, 24910, 25216, 25538, 25995, 26453];
    var olddata2 = [111, 144, 166, 183, 224, 255, 300, 336, 403, 483, 545, 598, 662, 734, 795, 854, 924, 1018, 1088, 1144, 1191, 1284, 1349, 1349, 1417, 1487, 1591, 1689, 1788, 1876, 1969, 2064, 2146, 2224, 2302, 2379, 2453, 2524, 2598, 2668, 2737, 2803, 2859, 2913, 2966, 3032, 3086];

    let myChart = (document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'));
    let myCovidChart = new Chart(myChart, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: label1,
        datasets: [{
          data: olddata,
          label: 'numero cumulativo dei Tamponi',
          borderColor: 'green',


        }, {
          data: olddata1,
          label: 'Numero incrementale dei contagiati',
          borderColor: 'red',


        }, {
          data: olddata2,
          label: 'Numero incrementale dei decessi',
          borderColor: 'blue',

        }]
      },
      options: {

      }
    });


    function updateChart() {
      myCovidChart.data.datasets[0].data = [74060, 78066, 83130, 89136, 94278, 99008, 102082, 107850, 113930, 120387, 127108, 132510, 137069, 140996, 146173, 152447, 158762, 164053, 170109];
      myCovidChart.update();
    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```